# CKEditor(5) - How to remove select table widget?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, css-tables, ckeditor5

I need to remove the widget that is used for table selection to prevent selecting and potentially deleting the entire table afterwards.

I just want to show and edit table data that I get in raw html string, without any other functionalities, toolbars, widgets, ...

Hiding this widget can be done by removing class names, but I hope there is a better way of doing this.

I suppose this widget is a part of Table plugin.
[image]

I want to get more clear look, like this:

[image]
I'm using `"react": "^16.8.3"` and `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^1.1.3"`.

This is my CKEditor React component config.

```js
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
...

<CKEditor
    editor={ClassicEditor}
    config={{
        toolbar: null          // To remove default CKEditor toolbar
    }}
    data={tableContent}
    disabled={disabled}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not support this functionality (it is impossible to achieve this through editor configuration), however, there are two directions / ideas we could point you if you'd like to try to write it yourself.

1. When the table becomes selected, you could turn read-only mode. This should prevent any modifications except of moving the selection to another place. Switch off read-only mode when the selection is changed.
2. Similarly, when the table is selected, you could disable `DeleteCommand`.

To check if the table is selected you need to check if the model selection contains exactly the table element.

Below, I link you to the important part of API docs:

- [`editor.model.document.selection`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_selection-Selection.html)
- [`editor.isReadOnly`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editor-Editor.html#member-isReadOnly)
- [`Command` class](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_command-Command.html) - check `forceDisabled` and `clearForceDisabled` methods
- [`editor.commands`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editor-Editor.html#member-commands) - to get a command

Comment: Data consists of tables only so they mustn't be in read-only mode. Each rendered CKEditor react component contains exactly one table. I just wanted to cover the use case where the whole table is deleted and some text is written instead of it.

Comment: I didn't mean that the table should be read-only. I mean to switch to read-only mode if **exactly** the table is selected, although I guess you still would be able to select a bigger part of the content and the table.

Comment: It's just a hack though, we didn't thought about cases where user would like to have some elements non-removable.

Answer (score 0):

After all, I just hid the widget. It doesn't completely prevent the selection but it looks cleaner and "selecting" space is very narrow.

```css
.ck.ck-widget__selection-handler {
  display: none;
}

.ck.ck-content.ck-editor__editable.ck-rounded-corners.ck-editor__editable_inline.ck-blurred > figure,
.ck.ck-content.ck-editor__editable.ck-rounded-corners.ck-editor__editable_inline.ck-focused > figure {
  margin: 16px 0;
}
```